# How can i make the button background slide effect with mask css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i make button background slide effect on hover with css ?

[image]

here is what i did : [jsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ppwL5hrz/3/)

same effect with icons and static text

Comment: Go through with this plugin http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Comment: Here they switch the color of text

Comment: It has lots of options, you'll have to play with the CSS to match your requirements, see their icons section

Comment: As per your JSfiddle, you should use SVG icon instead of image, this way you'll be able to handle it more easily.

Comment: i have lots of buttons with text, its multilanguage website, so SVG may not a good idea?

Comment: SVG is again good idea